# android layout: nested weights or relative view

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to assemble a layout that would be fairly easy to do with weights in that everything is either 1/2, 1/4 or 1/8 of its parent, but I've heard that doing nested weights is bad for loading/performance and that relative layouts are better.

To be honest, I don't like relative layouts.  I understand how to arrange things right next to or on top of something I've already put down, but struggle to understand how to arrange things in a manner similar to how I would with weighting.

This is a rough drawing of how I would like my layout to look like with the measurements on the sides.  I could easily do that left grouping (Header, Name, Image, Type, Rank/Tier) but I'm not sure how to arrange the other side especially in how to maintain the height of the description box so that the rest underneath doesn't move if the content of that box changes.

[Edit]* I will set it up to always be in landscape mode
[image: My rough layout drawing]

Answer (score 0):

You could have two RelativeLayouts. One for the left side, and one for the right side. That of course, would only work for landscape mode, in which case scrolling would be the only other option for portrait. So you can do

**Landscape**

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout..> RelativeLayout/>
    <RelativeLayout..> <RelativeLayout/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

**Portrait**

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout..> <RelativeLayout/>
    <RelativeLayout..> <RelativeLayout/>
<LinearLayout/>
```

So you still have control where the views lie in each section, but they still stay in each side respectively.

Comment: How do I keep the relative layouts "weighted" without using weights?  Or would I have to use 0.3 and 0.7 weight for that?

Comment: Well seeing as the Layout on the left is much smaller just use the weight to make sure its contents show, and the rest can be used by the one in the right.